# How can I fade HTML5 canvas ctx objects in and out using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I've created in HTML5 a canvas with some ctx objects that I would like to fade in and fade out constantly. Where do I have to put the jQuery code?

For example, I've got the following code for circle objects:

```
function drawClusters(ctx, x, y, r) {

    var startPoint = (Math.PI/180)*0;
    var endPoint = (Math.PI/180)*360;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,startPoint,endPoint,true);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,204)";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;

    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JQuery effects work by changing the CSS-style of DOM elements. But the canvas is not object-oriented. The HTML5 canvas works like a canvas in real-life. When you draw a line on a piece of paper, the only way to change it afterwards is to erase it with an eraser (potentially also damaging something else drawn there) or draw something over it which covers it.

When you draw something to a HTML5 canvas, it stops being an object and becomes a bunch of pixels on the canvas. The only way to change these pixels is to overdraw them with something else. That means JQuery will not work here.

You will have to implement this manually. Create [a rendering loop using requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) which constantly redraws you scene, but slightly changes the globalAlpha with every iteration.

Comment: It is necessary to redraw all the scene? I ve just want to redraw parts of my canvas.

Comment: @FereRes Depending on how the scene looks you might either get away with only erasing and redrawing a small rectangle of the canvas or you could layer multiple canvases on top of each other using CSS positioning, place all the changing content on one of them and only erase and redraw that canvas.